# How to cast JValue to bool?

Tags: c#, json.net, visual-studio-2017

Recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 and am facing a weird issue. I am not able to cast Netwonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to a bool.

For instance, here is my object "actualObj" which contains a bool (shown in QuickWatch):
[image: a JValue object containing a bool]

Now, when I cast it to a bool, which should have worked as per [the docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JValueCast.htm), I get an invalid cast exception:[image: invalid cast exception]

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to cast the `Value` property of the `JValue`:

```
JValue jv = actualObject as JValue;
if(jv != null)
{
    bool b = (bool)jv.Value;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Indeed, I didn't realize that the cast to JValue was missing :). I don't need jv.Value -- the (bool) cast on jv will work.